# Is there a clear option to create lazy loading module with CLI commands in angular?

Tags: angular-cli, lazy-loading

I have tried using the following command, but I am not able to do it.

"ng generate module supplier-site-map --module=app.module --route supplier-site-map"

It gives me error as shown in below

[image]

Anyone have suggestions on this?

Comment: The command you have entered seems to be correct and it's working correctly for me, even when I use version that's mentioned in the warning.

Comment: Could you please provide output of `ng --version` command from the project root?

Comment: Angular CLI: 8.3.29
Node: 14.17.3
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 8.2.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Comment: @angular-devkit/architect         0.803.29
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.29
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.29
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.29
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.29
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.29
@angular/cdk                      8.2.3
@angular/cli                      8.3.29
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.29
@schematics/angular               8.3.29
@schematics/update                0.803.29
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack - 4.46.0